# Spark binary file and Delta Table

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have batches of binary files (~3mb each) that I receive in batches of ~20000 files at a time. These files are used downstream for further processing, but I want to process them and store in Delta tables.

I can do this easily:

```
df = spark.read.format(“binaryFile”).load(<path-to-batch>)
df = df.withColumn(“id”, expr(“uuid()”)

dt = DeltaTable.forName(“myTable”)
dt.alias(“a”).merge(
    df.alias(“a”),
    “a.path = b.path”
).whenNotMatchedInsert(
    values={“id”: “b.id”, “content”: “b.content”}
).execute()
```

This makes the table quite slow already, but later I need to query certain IDs, do collect and write them individually back to binary files.

**Questions:**

1. Would my table benefit from a batch column and partition?
2. Should I partition by `id`? I know this is not ideal, but might make querying individual rows easier?
3. Is there a better way to write the files out again, rather than `.collect()`? I have seen when I select about 1000 specific ids write them out that about 10 minutes is just for collect and then less than a minute to write. I do something like:

```
for row in df.collect():
    with open(row.id, “wb”) as fw:
        fw.write(row.content)
```

Comment: I have to add that I have tested `partition by (id)` option and there is a 3 times speed up in querying, but I don't know what the effect is with 1mil+ rows/files will be.

Answer (score 0):

1. As uuid() returns random values, I'm afraid we cannot use it to compare existing data with new records. (Sorry if I misunderstood the idea)
2. I don't think using partition by id will help as the id column has obviously [high cardinality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/best-practices).
3. Instead of using collect() which loads all records into Driver, I think it would be better if you can write the records in the Spark dataframe directly and simultaneously from all the worker nodes into a temporary location on ADLS first and then aggregate a few data files from that location.